# Change default icon of drop_down menu (in Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using a select_tag:

```
 <%= select_tag :s_user_type, options_for_select(User.all.map(&:user_type).uniq.compact.collect{|e| [e]}, user_type), {  :multiple => false, prompt: 'I am looking for a ...', class: "input-lg dropdown-home form-control" } %>
```

which renders into the dropdown below. I am trying to figure out, how to change the default icon of the drop_down (up and down arrow shown in the circle below) with an icon of fontawesome (e.g. [this](http://fontawesome.io/icon/chevron-down/) ). Is this possible? If so, any clue how can i do this in Rails?

[image]

Comment: Try replacing the class with `class="fa fa-chevron-down"`.

Comment: @Pavan doesn't work...

Comment: How are getting your `current drop-down`? Through setting `class: "input-lg dropdown-home form-control"` right?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I am getting it with the select_tag. The class is just used for some CSS styles I applied.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript